# An ad seems to be downloading malware into my epub file

Tags: virus

How can an ad add malware to a website download link?

When I download from dailyuploads, If adblock is running, the file generally downloads clean, but if its not I get an Auto.KMS infection. This happens not just when I DL zips, but also Epubs as well.

Now, Dailyuploads requires all users to disable adblock.

Is there any other way to safely DL the file with adblock disabled?

Comment: No JS would be a good start.

Comment: @SmokeDispenser and not let me download my file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to rethink your use of DailyUploads. When I tried to get to it, Chrome warns me off saything that it is compromised - undoubtedly why you are getting inserted malware.

As such it seems very unlikely that it is safe to go there at all let alone with adblocking disabled.

Any site that disallows adblocking should be avoided if at all possible. There are far too many rogue adverts around that can bypass most protections.